# Can the same docker container be used for large concurrent jobs on jenkins master node?

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

We’ve got a Linux Jenkins instance running in AWS. The instance is a t3.large and there are some memory intensive jobs that run on the master node. Currently I’m unable to add agents so I’m having to run everything on master which I don’t like but I have to deal with.

One of the main issues I’m facing is when I try to run a few mem intensive Jenkins jobs concurrently using the same container, I either get an out of memory error or the container errors out of finishing the process. I’m unsure what the resolution is.

For instance since I can’t add agents to existing instance, would creating additional instances and running the memory intensive Jenkins job on master node solve this? I don’t know if the issue is with the docker containers memory limits or what.

I’ve tried trying to verify how much GB those Jenkins jobs are using to see if upping the instance size would work but I don’t know where to look. Some of these jobs take hours to complete because of the data being loading into rds schemas via scripts.